# Reinstall image on VM in Azure

Tags: azure

Is it possible to reinstall an operating system image on a given virtual machine in Azure (e.g. from Windows to Linux) without removing and again provisioning it?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the following link:

1. [Change the OS disk used by an Azure VM using PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/windows/os-disk-swap)
2. [How to map Azure Disks to Linux VM guest disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/linux/azure-to-guest-disk-mapping)
3. [Change the OS disk used by an Azure VM using the Azure CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/virtual-machines/linux/os-disk-swap)

Basically this can be done by changing the OS Disk, with Azure CLI you should use the following commands:

First MAKE SURE Azure CLI Version is greater than 2.0.25!

Use az disk list to get a list of the disks in your resource group.

```
az disk list \
   -g myResourceGroupDisk \
   --query '[*].{diskId:id}' \
   --output table
```

(Optional) Use az vm stop to stop\deallocate the VM before swapping the disks.

```
az vm stop \
   -n myVM \
   -g myResourceGroup
```

Use az vm update with the full resource ID of the new disk for the --osdisk parameter

```
az vm update \
   -g myResourceGroup \
   -n myVM \
   --os-disk /subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<resource group>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/myDisk
```

Restart the VM using az vm start.

```
az vm start \
   -n myVM \
   -g myResourceGroup
```